# difference between linux/elf.h, elf.h and sys/elf.h and which one I should be using

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I'm working with an old codebase. Needed to make a few changes and ran in the problem: conflicting declarations. The code essentially boils down to the following

```
#include <linux/elf.h>
#include <sys/auxv.h>
int main(void) {return 0;}
```

I compile it as `g++ test.cpp` and I'm getting the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:43:18: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef uint64_t Elf64_Xword’
   43 | typedef uint64_t Elf64_Xword;
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:22:15: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef __u64 Elf64_Xword’
   22 | typedef __u64 Elf64_Xword;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:44:18: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef int64_t Elf64_Sxword’
   44 | typedef int64_t  Elf64_Sxword;
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:23:15: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef __s64 Elf64_Sxword’
   23 | typedef __s64 Elf64_Sxword;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:48:18: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef uint64_t Elf64_Addr’
   48 | typedef uint64_t Elf64_Addr;
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:16:15: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef __u64 Elf64_Addr’
   16 | typedef __u64 Elf64_Addr;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:52:18: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef uint64_t Elf64_Off’
   52 | typedef uint64_t Elf64_Off;
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:19:15: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef __u64 Elf64_Off’
   19 | typedef __u64 Elf64_Off;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:83:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf32_Ehdr Elf32_Ehdr’
   83 | } Elf32_Ehdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:219:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf32_hdr Elf32_Ehdr’
  219 | } Elf32_Ehdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:101:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf64_Ehdr Elf64_Ehdr’
  101 | } Elf64_Ehdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:236:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf64_hdr Elf64_Ehdr’
  236 | } Elf64_Ehdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:397:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf32_Shdr Elf32_Shdr’
  397 | } Elf32_Shdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:314:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf32_shdr Elf32_Shdr’
  314 | } Elf32_Shdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:411:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf64_Shdr Elf64_Shdr’
  411 | } Elf64_Shdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:327:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf64_shdr Elf64_Shdr’
  327 | } Elf64_Shdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:527:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf32_Sym Elf32_Sym’
  527 | } Elf32_Sym;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:190:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf32_sym Elf32_Sym’
  190 | } Elf32_Sym;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:537:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf64_Sym Elf64_Sym’
  537 | } Elf64_Sym;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:199:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf64_sym Elf64_Sym’
  199 | } Elf64_Sym;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:638:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf32_Rel Elf32_Rel’
  638 | } Elf32_Rel;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:164:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf32_rel Elf32_Rel’
  164 | } Elf32_Rel;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:649:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf64_Rel Elf64_Rel’
  649 | } Elf64_Rel;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:169:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf64_rel Elf64_Rel’
  169 | } Elf64_Rel;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:658:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf32_Rela Elf32_Rela’
  658 | } Elf32_Rela;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:175:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf32_rela Elf32_Rela’
  175 | } Elf32_Rela;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:665:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf64_Rela Elf64_Rela’
  665 | } Elf64_Rela;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:181:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf64_rela Elf64_Rela’
  181 | } Elf64_Rela;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:689:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf32_Phdr Elf32_Phdr’
  689 | } Elf32_Phdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:253:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf32_phdr Elf32_Phdr’
  253 | } Elf32_Phdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:701:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf64_Phdr Elf64_Phdr’
  701 | } Elf64_Phdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:264:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf64_phdr Elf64_Phdr’
  264 | } Elf64_Phdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:838:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf32_Dyn Elf32_Dyn’
  838 | } Elf32_Dyn;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:144:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct dynamic Elf32_Dyn’
  144 | } Elf32_Dyn;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:848:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf64_Dyn Elf64_Dyn’
  848 | } Elf64_Dyn;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:152:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct Elf64_Dyn Elf64_Dyn’
  152 | } Elf64_Dyn;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:1168:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf32_Nhdr Elf32_Nhdr’
 1168 | } Elf32_Nhdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:437:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf32_note Elf32_Nhdr’
  437 | } Elf32_Nhdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h:22,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/elf.h:1175:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Elf64_Nhdr Elf64_Nhdr’
 1175 | } Elf64_Nhdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:444:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct elf64_note Elf64_Nhdr’
  444 | } Elf64_Nhdr;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Essentially the issue is that `auxv.h` includes `/usr/include/elf.h` which in turns conflicts with `/usr/include/linux/elf.h`

So my question is why have two different `elf.h` files? And the bigger question is what is the difference between `/usr/include`, `/usr/include/linux` and `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys` directories? There is an `elf.h` file in each of them. What dictates which directory I should be using in my `#include` statements? I fee like I don't know something very important.

Comment: linux/elf.h is a kernel dev file. You must include sys/elf.h if you are developing an user space app. You must include linux/elf.h if you are developing a kernel driver or low level lib like libc, that provides sys/elf.h for user space apps.

Comment: @S.M. What about `/usr/include/elf.h`? When do I include this file?

Comment: /usr/include/elf.h is more than sys/elf.h. Include it depending on your requirements.

Comment: My take would be that you should be using `<elf.h>` (aka `/usr/include/elf.h`) unless you're writing something in the kernel.  See `man 5 elf` — it indicates that you should use `#include <elf.h>`.  Also look for `libelf` — the Linux machine I'm using hasn't got the manual for that installed, but a Google search ('libelf documentation') finds references for me.

Comment: [plain elf.h is from glibc](https://code.woboq.org/linux/include/elf.h.html) - I think this is the one you want for user-space stuff

Comment: @S.M. I don't understand. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "more than sys/elf.h. Include it depending on your requirements.". If you can come up with examples, it would be appreciated.

Comment: This means elf.h has more declarations than sys/elf.h.

Comment: @S.M. So what would be the case when I should be using `elf.h` vs `sys/elf.h` or `linux/elf.h`?

Comment: Call a required function or use a required constant. Read the manual and look at the include sections.

Comment: `sys/elf.h` is obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: @S.M. What manual are you talking about? Do you mean `man <search item>`?